# Formatting big decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a big decimal with value:                              -6
I need to format it in order to obtain:       -000000006.00
If my big decimal is *6*, the result will be: 0000000006.00

I am trying to use `String.format`, but I can't get that result.

```
String.format("%010d", invoice.getAmount().doubleValue());
```

How can I format my big decimal to get the desired results?

Comment: Show us your code please?

Comment: Let me guess, you also get an Exception? Use `f` instead of `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String result = String.format("%013.2f", invoice.getAmount());
```

Note that the symbol used for the decimal point is locale-specific; you might for example get `,` instead of `.`. If you need it to always be dot `.` then specify a locale for which the decimal point is a dot, for example:

```
String result = String.format(Locale.US, "%013.2f", invoice.getAmount());
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class:

```
BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal(-6);
DecimalFormat df = (bg.signum() < 0) ? new DecimalFormat("000000000.00") : new DecimalFormat("0000000000.00");
System.out.println(df.format(bg));
```

Yields:

```
-000000006.00
0000000006.00
```

Comment: It's not necessary to do `.doubleValue()`, and you shouldn't, because it might introduce rounding errors. Just pass the `BigDecimal` to `format` directly.

Comment: The version with the positive value should contain one additional zero, so both results would have the exact same "length". At least this is the case in OPs example. I prefer your current results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `String.format()` you can use '+' to include the sign:

```
String.format("%+010d", -6)
```